# Containerrizing Hosted Blazor WebAssembly for Raspberry Pi Docker Swarm

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I’m developing a DotNet Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly, as a frontend to my backend ASPNet Core API, running on Raspberry Pi’s, containerised in a Docker Swarm.

I’m developing on a MacBook Pro, using VSCode for Mac, and it’s really a great tool. I created the solution as “dotnet new blazorwasm —hosted” and got the solution created and build.

I have installed Docker Desktop, and created a Buildx builder for arm, which works great with all my other solutions (DotNet Core API, DotNet Background solutions), but with the hosted blazorwasm solution, I run into several problems, probably caused by my lacking knowledge on setting up build options.

So I installed Visual Studio 2019 (I have used VS on Windows for 20 years) and was actually surprised over the look and feel, a really great tool.

I created the hosted Blazor WebAssembly solution, which works great om Mac, and even the Docker desktop integration work without problems.

Building the Docker Image was easy, I just used my Buildx builder, and executed below command from the command line:

“docker buildx build --file ./SnakeConsole/Server/Dockerfile --platform linux/arm/v7  -t jagdriver/wavesnake:SnakeConsole3 --push .”

On the Raspberry Swarm, I then created the Stack/Container. The Stack installed **but the container refused to start**, and the log was:

*standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused “exec format error”.*

I have seen this error before, and as far as I remember I added “-r ubuntu.19.10-arm” to the dotnet publish command to ensure that the code is generated for linux-arm.

So I tried to add “-r ubuntu.19.10-arm” to the dotnet publish command in below dockerfile, and execute the Docker buildx build command again, but then the Build Engine run into below error.

*project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0/browser-wasm'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'browser-wasm' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers*

***Can anyone out the give me a helping hand on this, thanks in advance.***

**FACTS:**

1. The solution I’m mentioning is the standard Hosted Blazor
   WebAssembly template without any changes.
2. The target framework is .Net 5.0
3. Visual Studio for Mac community is version 8.7.2 (build 4)

**Docker file from the default hosted Blazor WebAssembly template.**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY SnakeConsole/Server/SnakeConsole.Server.csproj SnakeConsole/Server/
COPY SnakeConsole/Client/SnakeConsole.Client.csproj SnakeConsole/Client/
COPY SnakeConsole/Shared/SnakeConsole.Shared.csproj SnakeConsole/Shared/
RUN dotnet restore "SnakeConsole/Server/SnakeConsole.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SnakeConsole/Server"
RUN dotnet build "SnakeConsole.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SnakeConsole.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SnakeConsole.Server.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have faced similar issue, documentation says:

> Deploying a standalone Blazor WebAssembly app to Azure App Service for Linux isn't currently supported. A Linux server image to host the app isn't available at this time. Work is in progress to enable this scenario.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#standalone-deployment

Looks like this is a Docker OS compatibility and framework functionality issue. I would suggest to target your app to Server (Blazor Server Hosting model scenario).